# How to save attribute which is being overridden as nil?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The `ranking` only saves if the user saved it under the note that was first in chronological order.

[image]

**challenges/show**

```
<% @challenge.dates_challenged.first(@challenge.days_challenged + @challenge.missed_days).each_with_index do |date, i| %>
  <% if @notes.any? { |note| note.notes_date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") == date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") } %>
    <% @notes.each do |note| %>
      <% if note.notes_text.present? %>
        <% if note.notes_date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") == date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %>
          <div class="notes-notes-background">
            <% if note.ranking == 1 %>
              <%= image_tag '1.png', class: 'note-emoticon' %>
            <% elsif note.ranking == 2 %>
              <%= image_tag '2.png', class: 'note-emoticon' %>
            <% elsif note.ranking == 3 %>
              <%= image_tag '3.png', class: 'note-emoticon' %>
            <% elsif note.ranking == 4 %>
              <%= image_tag '4.png', class: 'note-emoticon' %>
            <% end %>
            <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; color: #a0b4f0;">DAY <%= i + 1 %></div>
            <b><%= note.notes_date.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></b><br><br>
            <div style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;">
              <%= link_to edit_note_path(note) do %>
                <%= simple_format note.notes_text %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      <% else %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <div class="notes-form-background" style="padding-top: 1em;">
      <div style="margin-bottom: -19px; color: #a0b4f0; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; color: #a0b4f0;">DAY <%= i + 1 %></div><br>
      <div style="color: #eee;"><%= date.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></div>
      <div style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;">
        <%= render 'notes/form', :date => date %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**notes/form**

```
<%= form_for [@notable, @note] do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field(:ranking, id: 'ranking') %>
  <%= image_tag('1.png', data: { ranking: 1 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
  <%= image_tag('2.png', data: { ranking: 2 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
  <%= image_tag('3.png', data: { ranking: 3 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
  <%= image_tag('4.png', data: { ranking: 4 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
<% end %>

<script>
  $('.image-clicker').click(function() {
    $('#ranking').val($(this).data('ranking'));
    $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked')
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
  });
</script>
```

Everything else from the note is being saved such as the `text`, just not the `ranking`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have ONE and only ONE html id with the same name on a page. In your case, all your hidden fields have the same id `#ranking`.

Your jQuery selector will pick the first. Which explains why you're facing the issue.

Just give your hidden field a class and inside your click function, search the children for the ranking hidden field.

Comment: Wow I love such a simple solution haha and to think how many hours I just spent on that. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad to hear this helped! Btw, you need to simplify your code quite a bit. You have a fat view. Also, don't put scripts in views AND don't put styles in there too =) Best of luck!